# Is it possible to get 'Session User" to display

Tags: php, mysql

Hi there I'm trying to get a user who comments and is logged in to their account for their 'Login Name' to display when they comment currenlty when a user wants to comment it asks for their name and their comment. Is it possible to display their name getting it from the session to display it? Thanks!

[http://puu.sh/cByNU/697e58cdf6.jpg http://puu.sh/cByNU/697e58cdf6.jpg](http://puu.sh/cByNU/697e58cdf6.jpg)

On the image I'm logged in as 'Testing' is it possible to remove the field 'Name' and when they post a comment it will get their name where the search box is (testing).

Thanks!

My CODE:

```
<?php
 session_start();
 include "../includes/config.php";
  include "function.php";
  include ('../includes/header.php'); 
?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
<head>
<title>Honda</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Julius+Sans+One' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href="../css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
<!--start lightbox -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/jquery.lightbox.css">
<script src="../js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/jquery.lightbox.js"></script>
<script>
  // Initiate Lightbox
  $(function() {
    $('.gallery1 a').lightbox(); 
  });
</script>

</head>
<body>
<!--start header-->
<div class="h_bg">
<div class="wrap">
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="header">
    <div class="logo">
         <a href="index.php"><img src="../images/logo.png"> </a>
    </div>
    <div class="cssmenu">
    <ul>
       <li><a href="index.php"><span>Home</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="about.php"><span>About</span></a></li>
       <li class="active" class="has-sub"><a href="service.php"><span>Gallery</span></a>
       </li>
       <li class="last"><a href="contact.php"><span>Contact</span></a></li>
     <div class="clear"></div>

     <form action="search.php" method="GET">
                     <div class="search">
                    <h2>search</h2>
            <form>

                <input type="text" name="query" placeholder="Enter Your search..." />
                <input type="submit" value="">
            </form>
        </div>
        </form>

                                 <div class="search1">


            <form action="" method="POST">
        <br>
 <h2>Welcome, <?=$_SESSION['sess_user'];?>!</h2><br><br>
                                <div class="pw">
                <a href="changepassword.php"><h3>Change details</h3></a>
                </div>

                <br><br>
 <h2><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></h2>
    </form> 
    </div>



    </div>
     </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<!-- start content -->
<div class="content_bg">
<div class="wrap">
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="main">
<div class="ser-main">
        <h2 class="style">Gallery of honda</h2>
        <div class="ser-grid-list img_style">
        <div class="gallery1">
            <a href="../images/ser_pic1.jpg"><img src="../images/ser_pic1.jpg" alt=""></a>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ser-grid-list img_style">
        <div class="gallery1">
            <a href="../images/ser_pic2.jpg"><img src="../images/ser_pic2.jpg" alt=""></a>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ser-grid-list img_style">
        <div class="gallery1">
            <a href="../images/ser_pic3.jpg"><img src="../images/ser_pic3.jpg" alt=""></a>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ser-grid-list img_style">
        <div class="gallery1">
            <a href="../images/ser_pic4.jpg"><img src="../images/ser_pic4.jpg" alt=""></a>
        </div>










        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="footer_bg">
<div class="wrap">
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="footer">

                <div class="search69">


        <?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])  
    && !empty($_POST['name']) 
    && !empty($_POST['comment']) ){

$name=$_POST['name'];
$comment=$_POST['comment'];
$submit=$_POST['submit'];


$insert=mysql_query("INSERT INTO comment (name,comment) VALUES ('$name','$comment') ");
echo "<meta HTTP-EQUIV='REFRESH' content='0; url=service.php'>";
}
else
{
echo "";
}
?>





        <form class="comments" action="service.php" method="POST">



<h2>Name: </h2><br><input type="text" name="name" required/><br><br>
<h2>Comment:</h2><textarea name="comment" rows="10" cols="50"  required></textarea><br><br><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Comment">

</form>



<?php


$getquery=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comment ORDER BY id DESC");
while($rows=mysql_fetch_assoc($getquery))
{
$id=$rows['id'];
$date=$rows['date'];
$name=$rows['name'];
$comment=$rows['comment'];
echo '<h2><hr size="1"/><br><font color="green">' . $name .  '</font><h2><br/>' . '<br/>' . $comment .  '<br/><br><font color="red">' . $date. '</font><br/>' . '<hr size="1"/>'
;}



?>





</div>
        <div class="copy">
            <p class="w3-link">2014&nbsp;</p>
            <a href="terms.php">Privacy & Policy</a>



        </div>
                <div class="f_nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Skype</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Linked in</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Twitter</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Facebook</a></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

(ALL MY CODE ON THAT PAGE)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE:

The guys here will kill me, because now i am just edited your code, and not rewrite to mysqli or PDO, but as i saw, you stuck, so i've just updated, bacause i do not want to confuse with that too. I do some modifications, check my comments about that. (Moved the block of insertion to the top of file, add an error message, remove unnecesarry variables, rename the rows variable to row, etc...)

```
<?php
session_start();
include "../includes/config.php";
include "function.php";
include ('../includes/header.php');

//Set an empty errorMsg because later we will check it.
$errorMsg = '';

//If everything is set, or the SESSION["sess_user"] not empty.
//I moved this whole thing here, because if there are no output, we can
//redirect user from PHP, and do not need to use META REFREHS...
if (isset($_POST['submit']) && !empty($_POST['comment']) && (!empty($_POST["name"]) || !empty($_SESSION["sess_user"]))) {
    if (!empty($_SESSION["sess_user"])) {
        $name = $_SESSION["sess_user"];
    } else {
        $name = $_POST["name"];
    }
    //$comment = $_POST['comment']; //Use $_POST["comment"] directly
    //$submit = $_POST['submit']; //Do not use it anywhere
    $insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO comment (name,comment) VALUES ('" . mysql_real_escape_string($name) . "','" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["comment"]) . "')");
    Header("Location: service.php");
} else {
    $errorMsg = "You need to fill all the fields.";
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Honda</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Julius+Sans+One' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link href="../css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
        <!--start lightbox -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/jquery.lightbox.css">
        <script src="../js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../js/jquery.lightbox.js"></script>
        <script>
            // Initiate Lightbox
            $(function() {
                $('.gallery1 a').lightbox();
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!--start header-->
        <div class="h_bg">
            <div class="wrap">
                <div class="wrapper">
                    <div class="header">
                        <div class="logo">
                            <a href="index.php"><img src="../images/logo.png"> </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="cssmenu">
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="index.php"><span>Home</span></a></li>
                                <li><a href="about.php"><span>About</span></a></li>
                                <li class="active" class="has-sub"><a href="service.php"><span>Gallery</span></a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="last"><a href="contact.php"><span>Contact</span></a></li>
                                <div class="clear"></div>

                                <form action="search.php" method="GET">
                                    <div class="search">
                                        <h2>search</h2>
                                        <form>

                                            <input type="text" name="query" placeholder="Enter Your search..." />
                                            <input type="submit" value="">
                                        </form>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                                <div class="search1">
                                    <form action="" method="POST">
                                        <br>
                                        <h2>Welcome, <?= $_SESSION['sess_user']; ?>!</h2><br><br>
                                        <div class="pw">
                                            <a href="changepassword.php"><h3>Change details</h3></a>
                                        </div>
                                        <br><br>
                                        <h2><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></h2>
                                    </form> 
                                </div>
                        </div>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- start content -->
    <div class="content_bg">
        <div class="wrap">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <div class="main">
                    <div class="ser-main">
                        <h2 class="style">Gallery of honda</h2>
                        <div class="ser-grid-list img_style">
                            <div class="gallery1">
                                <a href="../images/ser_pic1.jpg"><img src="../images/ser_pic1.jpg" alt=""></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="ser-grid-list img_style">
                            <div class="gallery1">
                                <a href="../images/ser_pic2.jpg"><img src="../images/ser_pic2.jpg" alt=""></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="ser-grid-list img_style">
                            <div class="gallery1">
                                <a href="../images/ser_pic3.jpg"><img src="../images/ser_pic3.jpg" alt=""></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="ser-grid-list img_style">
                            <div class="gallery1">
                                <a href="../images/ser_pic4.jpg"><img src="../images/ser_pic4.jpg" alt=""></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="footer_bg">
            <div class="wrap">
                <div class="wrapper">
                    <div class="footer">
                        <div class="search69">
                            <?php
                            //Added here the errorMsg
                            if (!empty($errorMsg)) {
                                ?>
                                <div class="error"><?php echo $errorMsg; ?></div>
                                <?php
                            }
                            ?>
                            <form class="comments" action="service.php" method="POST">
                                <?php
                                if (!empty($_SESSION['sess_user'])) {
                                    //If user logged in, use the name of it
                                    ?>
                                    <h2>Name: </h2><br><?php echo $_SESSION['sess_user']; ?>
                                    <br><br>
                                    <?php
                                } else {
                                    //Else, ask it
                                    ?>
                                    <h2>Name: </h2><br><input type="text" name="name" required/><br><br>
                                    <?php
                                }
                                ?>

                                <h2>Comment:</h2><textarea name="comment" rows="10" cols="50"  required></textarea><br><br><br>
                                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Comment">
                            </form>

                            <?php
                            $getquery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comment ORDER BY id DESC");
                            //This is one row, not rows
                            while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($getquery)) {
                                /*
                                 * These are not necessary
                                $id = $rows['id'];
                                $date = $rows['date'];
                                $name = $rows['name'];
                                $comment = $rows['comment'];
                                 */
                                echo '<h2><hr size="1"/><br><font color="green">' . $row['name'] . '</font><h2><br/>' . '<br/>' . $row['comment'] . '<br/><br><font color="red">' . $row['date'] . '</font><br/>' . '<hr size="1"/>'
                                ;
                            }
                            ?>

                        </div>
                        <div class="copy">
                            <p class="w3-link">2014&nbsp;</p>
                            <a href="terms.php">Privacy & Policy</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="f_nav">
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">Skype</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Linked in</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Twitter</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Facebook</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**NOTE:** Do not use mysql functions since they are deprecated. use mysqli or PDO functions instead.

Acoid for sql injections, so escape your data!

Comment: Where do you suggest I put the second piece of code?

Comment: See my edited code. Before you insert the comment into the database.

Comment: Please excuse my ignorance but I am struggling :( I inserted it here please correct me if I'm wrong. http://puu.sh/cBzpj/b1447349ec.png

Comment: Ah, ok, i see what is the problem. Because if you use the `$_SESSION["sess_user"]` then `$_POST["name"]` will empty. Waint while i updated my code.

Comment: Check now. What i modified is this: `if (isset($_POST['submit']) && !empty($_POST['comment']) && (!empty($_POST["name"]) || !empty($_SESSION["sess_user"]))) {` it means, if the `$_POST["submit"]` was set, and comment is not empty, and (if `$_POST["name"]` **OR** `$_SESSION["sess_user"]` not empty), then... so it checks, is all the required fields are set, or if there are no `$_POST["username"]` then is the `$_SESSION["sess_user"]` did set. Got it?

Comment: Thanks for the help, are you able to edit it above in your post as it's a bit hard to see as it's squished up? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If i got it well, you want the form to automatically gets the name of a logged user. You should:

```
<?php $username = isset($_SESSION['sess_user']) ? $_SESSION['sess_user'] : "";?>
```

To store the username or "" into $username, depending on whether user is authentified or not. Then in your input line within the form:

```
<h2>Name: </h2><br><input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $username; ?>" required/><br><br>
```